# Integrating $\int xe^{-x} dx$ without parts

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

Can $\int xe^{-x} dx$ ever be solved by integration by substitution **without using parts**. Or does, as I suspect, substitution fail to yield a solution in this case.

Seems that we can't get a reciprocal to cancel $x$ out under any circumstance. I know how to solve with parts, please don't use this.

Comment: If it does fail, mathematically, why?

Comment: Sorry not to answer your question but it made wondering why don't you want to use integration by parts? Using it would not be a case of "killing a fly with a rocket-launcher"

Comment: Consider $-\int e^{-\alpha x}=\alpha^{-1}e^{-\alpha x}$. Differentiate both side w.r.t. $\alpha$ and set $\alpha=1$.

Comment: @A.S. I haven't done calculus in 3 years, so could you help me out slightly more? How do I get from $\int xe^{-x} dx$ to $-\int e^{-\alpha x}$? Where does the leading $x$ go?

Comment: @A.S. It is very elegant. Why don't you post an answer explaining the underlying philosophy ?

Comment: Ah, I've gazumped you, A.S. I'll make my answer CW.

Comment: Both of the answers fit, but another way - just guess

Comment: @Claude This is often called "Feynman integration trick" and it can be fruitful for many seemingly difficult integrals. The idea is to write $I(\alpha)=\int f(x,\alpha)\,dx$ such that you can find $I'(\alpha)$ (after differentiating under the integral sign) easily and then integrating $I'(\alpha)$ will yield $I(\alpha_0)$.

Comment: @A.S. Thanks ! It is a so smart way to solve monsters ! Cheers.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT! IT IS VERY ANNOYING TO READ TITLES WRITTEN LIKE THAT! THANKS!

Comment: We _differentiate_ instead, $D(xe^{-x})=e^{-x}-xe^{-x}=-D(e^{-x})-xe^{-x}$. Moving things around we find $xe^{-x}=D\bigl(-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}\bigr)$, so $\int xe^{-x}\,dx=-e^{-x}(1+x)+C$.

Comment: @mickep This is exactly integration by parts: $d(uv)=udv+vdu$ and "move things around".

Comment: @A.S. I agree partially (and that is why I put it as a comment). Imagine, the function to integrate was $x\cos x$ instead. No problems with integration by parts, but this time it does not work to _differentiate_ $x\cos x$ to get the result. It is a lucky coincidence with our function... (Yes, I'm not too serious with this.)

Comment: @mickep $D^2(x\cos x)=2D(\cos x)-x\cos$ - no problems either. But since you agree *partially*, I won't further *differentiate*.

Comment: @mickep Or even simpler $D(x\sin x)=x\cos x+D(-\cos x)$

Answer (score 6):

Differentiation under the integral sign.

The integral is precisely $$-\frac{1}{a} \dfrac{d}{da} \int e^{-a x} \ dx$$
evaluated at $a=1$.

But that is $$-\dfrac{1}{a} \dfrac{d}{da} \left(-\frac{1}{a} e^{-ax} \right) = -\frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{e^{-ax}}{a^2} + \frac{e^{-a x}x}{a} \right)$$

Evaluating at $1$ yields $$-(e^{-x} + x e^{-x}) = -e^{-x}(1+x)$$

Answer (score 3):

**By method of undetermined coefficients**

Guessing the anti-derivative $F(x)$ is in the form of $(A+Bx)e^{-x}$, then $F'(x)=-Ae^{-x}+Be^{-x}-Bxe^{-x}$ implying $B=-1$ and $B-A=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{e^{-x}, xe^{-x}\}$. Differentiating each element of the basis we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}) &= -e^{-x}\\
\frac{d}{dx}(xe^{-x}) &=e^{-x} + -xe^{-x}
\end{align*}

The matrix representation of the derivative operator with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is

$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$T^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 -1\\
0 -1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So

$$\int xe^{-x} \operatorname{d}\!x = T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix} = -e^{-x} - xe^{-x}.$$

Comment: i like it +1, where have you fond this method please @jessicaK ?

Comment: @Hamza I'm sorry, I don't have a source for you. I've never seen it in a book, probably because it isn't very useful. I found this one day after first learning about half-derivatives and trying to figure out how one might define a half-integral; the square root of a matrix seemed like the natural course of action.

Comment: @Hamza I wasn't the original poster but after a bit of browsing around i found [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20220104201753/https://www.mathematics.pitt.edu/sites/default/files/abstracts/IntegrationMatrices_1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Since a solution by substitution is required, substitute $y=x$, then proceed as in one of the other answers that involve neither parts, nor substitution.

Comment: This is… facetious.

Comment: How is this helpful to me?

Since a solution to the Riemann hypothesis is required.

State the Riemann hypothesis and proceed to complete a correct proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $$e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}$$ then 
\begin{align}
\int x e^{-x}dx&=\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}}{n!}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\int x^{n+1}dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n+2}}{n!(n+2)}+k\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)(-1)^{n+2}x^{n+2}}{(n+2)!}+k\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}+k\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\big)(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}+k\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{n!}\big)(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\big)(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}+k\\
&=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+1+k\\
&=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+k'\\
\end{align}